Positive monotonic transformation
I want to draw an indifference curve for this preference relation on $ℝ^2$
$$x ≿ y \leftrightarrow  (x_1+x_2)^2 ≥ (y_1+y_2)^2$$
Can I just take the square root(and then drop the absolute value sign since I only operate in the first quadrant)? This would give me the preference relation
$$x ≿ y \leftrightarrow  x_1+x_2 ≥ y_1+y_2 $$
Which has the utility function $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$.  I know that if ≿ is a preference relation on ℝ and u(x) is a utility function that represents it. Then v(x) also represents ≿ if and only if v(x) = f(u(x)) for every x, where f:ℝ $\rightarrow$ℝ is strictly increasing on the set of values taken by u
So this means, that if u(x) ≥ u(y), then x ≿ y. And since I have shown that $x ≿ y \leftrightarrow (x_1+x_2)^2 ≥ (y_1+y_2)^2$ can be written as $x ≿ y \leftrightarrow x_1+x_2 ≥ y_1+y_2$, since it "fulfills" the preference x ≿ y.
However, I am not sure if my positive monotonic preference is correct, since this is the first time I have ever done it, and I am very new in this topic.

Yes, what you are doing is fine.
